# Get Object from Delegate Filter Expression Expression<Func<T,bool>>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

Using lambda delegate Expression> - where my expression takes a Role object (POCO).

Looking to use that POCO Role object and map it to a data layer Role object with matching properties.  To do that, I need to be able to get the Role object from the delegate.

Example:

```
public List<Role> FindAll(Expression<Func<Role, bool>> filter)
```

Calling this method like:

```
FindAll(r => r.Name == role.Name);
```

r is type Role, and within the FindAll function, I can see that filter has one parameter, as such:

[image]

Can I extract that object?  And how?

I'm sure it MUST be doable, after all, linq does it internally all the time...

Comment: Why are you duplicating `Where`?

Comment: Have you tried casting them to the specialized `Expression`'s?

Comment: @leppie 1) What do you mean, 'Why am I duplicating `Where`?  2) Parameter[0] is of type ParameterExpression - so far I haven't found any properties off of that I can cast to my own type from, but I'm still trying.

Comment: The debugger is listing all the types for you already. Just cast to that, and viola, you have the properties you see in the debugger. It is a fairly trivial task, no magic involved :)

Comment: No, it isn't.  Filter is of type System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression.  Parameter[0] is of type ParameterExpression.   The Type property on ParameterExpression is returning the Type of object represented, but not the actual object itself.  Can't cast that.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Why can’t you cast that, exactly?

Comment: Are you trying to determine the Type of the parameter? The reason why I ask is because you ask about extracting an object and there is no object to extract other than the delegate.

Comment: (Role)filter yields: Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Entity.Role,bool>>' to 'Entity.Role'.  (Role)filter.Parameters[0] yields: (Role)filter.Parameters[0]
Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' to 'Entity.Role'

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo it's a delegate parameter, not an object. You definitely can't cast it to a Role. i.e. there is no Role object.

Comment: @RoyGoode Well, I'm hoping that since the delegate is using a Role object, there's a way to get a reference to the Role object the delegate is using.

Comment: Followup: Right - I'm not trying to cast it.  That was leppie's suggestion.  I'm trying to get to the object that's being used inside the delegate itself.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo It's a delegate method expecting a parameter of type Role. Surely there's no Role object in existence until the method is invoked? e.g. 
    Role myRoleObjectToInvokeTheMethod = new Role();
    var compiledFilter = filter.Compile();
    var resultValue = compiledFilter(myRoleObjectToInvokeTheMethod);

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo You didn’t read properly. Nowhere did leppie say that you should cast to `Role` – of course you should cast to the appropriate type, which the debugger tells you (`ParameterExpression`).

Comment: @RoyGoode Sure but at invocation, the delegate method DOES have a parameter expression that knows about the underlying type its using (as in the T of Func<T, bool>). That underlying type has been instantiated in the invocation of the delegate - so I'm trying to get to it, if at all possible.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right - I misunderstood leppie.  Re-reading it, I guess I don't understand - what kind of specialized expression would I cast it to?

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo OK, so you want to find out the Type in code: Type delegateParameterType = filter.Parameters[0].Type;

Comment: @RoyGoode No, that wasn't what I was going for - but Bryan's answer crystallized it for me.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo No problem, I can see your response to Bryan's answer provides us with a better explanation of what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two roles here: `r`, which represents the filter parameter, and `role`, which is an object that is closed over by the lambda expression. I assume you mean you want a reference to the `role` object, since you already found the `ParameterExpression` which represents `r`.

That object will be a `ConstantExpression` whose type is `Role`, and it will be the value of the `Expression` property of the `MemberAccessExpression` which represents `role.Name`. That will be the right-hand side of the `BinaryOperator` expression representing the equality test, which serves as the `Body` of the lambda expression.

Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes and no.  No, it's not what I really wanted - but reading your explanation has helped crystallize why it won't work.  (r=>r.name = role.name) is only one type of possible filters.  I could just as easily say (r=>r.name="Fred") - which would never have a role object so of course, why would that object *be* there...